# How to find out which page is the default?

Tags: asp.net, .net-3.5

Is there a generic way out there to find out which page of an asp.net 3.5 application running under IIS 6.0 (yea I know boring stuff) is the default one so I can do something like this:

```
   Response.Redirect(Helper.GetDefaultPage());
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could just try doing `Response.Redirect("/");` which will send them to the root and let IIS handle figuring out which page is the default.

Comment: ok i was expecting to see something as easy as this - great answer.

Comment: @Max - Except if your application isn't in the root of the domain, you'll have a problem.  Do a `Response.Redirect("~/")` (or probably `Response.Redirect(Page.ResolveUrl("~/"))`) instead.